# malloc on armadillo object

Tags: c++, malloc, armadillo

What is the convention to call malloc on an armadillo matrix instance.

Is this correct if I want to pre-allocate memory for a 100 x 100 matrix?

```
fmat* squareMat  = (fmat*)malloc(sizeof(fmat(100,100)));
```

Comment: Why are you even trying to use `malloc` in a C++ program ?

Answer (score 6):

No, it’s not the right way. `malloc` has no place in a C++ program at all. The right way of allocating the object is like this:

```
fmat squareMat(100, 100);
```

This can be easily seen by [reading the documentation](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#Mat).